# Nativescript - iOS build fails with error code 2

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have been trying to build the iOS version using Nativescript sidekick for two days now without luck. It used to build just fine in the past.

**Environment information**

1. Sidekick Version: 1.19.2-v.2019.11.18.2 (latest)
2. NativeScript CLI version: 6.2.2
3. CLI extension nativescript-cloud version: 1.19.3
4. CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits version: 0.3.5

**Error** : Build failed with error code 2

> The following build commands failed:
>   CompileC /tmp/builds/*/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.o /tmp/builds/*/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   CompileC /tmp/builds/*/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.o /tmp/builds/*/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   CompileC /tmp/builds/*/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.o /tmp/builds/*/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (3 failures)

**Build log**

```js
[19-12-11 14:50:46.544] NativeScript Sidekick version: 1.19.2-v.2019.11.18.2
[19-12-11 14:50:46.630] Checking for updates...
[19-12-11 14:50:48.133] No updates available.
[19-12-11 14:50:48.345] Dependencies versions: NodeJS: 10.16.0, npm: 6.9.0, NativeScript CLI: 6.2.2.
[19-12-11 14:50:52.017] (CLI) Using NativeScript CLI located in C:\Users\shobhitvaish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript
[19-12-11 14:50:56.349] (CLI) Searching for devices...
[19-12-11 14:50:56.571] Loaded CLI extension nativescript-cloud, version 1.19.3.
[19-12-11 14:50:56.573] Loaded CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits, version 0.3.5.
[19-12-11 14:51:01.548] The user Shobhit Vaish logged in.
[19-12-11 14:51:03.443] App with path: C:\MyStuff\Workspace\Dizz Loyalty\DizzLoyalty.App was opened.
[19-12-11 14:51:11.486] Devices service initialized.
[19-12-11 16:50:46.664] Checking for updates...
[19-12-11 16:50:50.248] No updates available.
[19-12-11 18:09:59.816] App with path: C:\MyStuff\Workspace\Dizz Loyalty\DizzLoyalty.App was opened.
[19-12-11 18:11:49.484] Build started.
[19-12-11 18:11:51.228] (CLI) Starting Cloud build. Cloud operation id: 8bd81af6-a195-4671-b2b4-b9dad47c57be
[19-12-11 18:11:51.228] (CLI) Getting accounts information...
[19-12-11 18:11:52.300] Build failed. {"message":"Internal server error"}
[19-12-11 18:12:24.658] Build started.
[19-12-11 18:12:25.320] (CLI) Starting Cloud build. Cloud operation id: dea14f7e-b68c-4032-8c9b-89a3982f7212
[19-12-11 18:12:25.320] (CLI) Getting accounts information...
[19-12-11 18:12:26.214] (CLI) Using account 56aa436d-0a06-4f9a-a45a-727797222675.
[19-12-11 18:12:26.217] (CLI) Cloud build of 'C:\MyStuff\Workspace\Dizz Loyalty\DizzLoyalty.App', platform: 'iOS', configuration: 'Release'.
[19-12-11 18:12:26.426] Prepare step started.
[19-12-11 18:12:26.529] (CLI) Copying template files...
[19-12-11 18:12:42.176] (CLI) Platform ios successfully added. v6.2.0
[19-12-11 18:12:42.176] (CLI) Preparing project...
[19-12-11 18:12:42.180] (CLI) Stripping the snapshot flag. Bear in mind that snapshot is only available in Android release builds.
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) Hash: fa2a14872eafe4cfffbe
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) Version: webpack 4.27.1
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) Time: 170453ms
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) Built at: 12/11/2019 6:15:42 PM
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)                                             Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)                                              4.js   18.7 KiB       4  [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)                                              5.js   12.7 KiB       5  [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)                                              6.js   13.2 KiB       6   [emitted]  runtime
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules.js  241 bytes       3  [emitted]  tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)                                         vendor.js   1.68 MiB       0  [emitted]  vendor
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI) Entrypoint tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules = runtime.js vendor.js tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules.js
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)   [4] ../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js + 9 modules 238 KiB {0} [built]
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)       |    10 modules
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)  [13] ./app/core/services/ui.service.ts 1.37 KiB {2} [built]
   
--------------------------------------

[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)       | ./app/app-routing.module.ts 703 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)       |     + 18 hidden modules
[19-12-11 18:15:42.070] (CLI)     + 514 hidden modules
[19-12-11 18:15:42.073] (CLI) Webpack compilation complete.
[19-12-11 18:15:42.804] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: C:\MyStuff\Workspace\Dizz Loyalty\DizzLoyalty.App\platforms\ios\.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
[19-12-11 18:15:42.804] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
[19-12-11 18:15:42.957] (CLI) Project successfully prepared (ios)
[19-12-11 18:15:42.974] (CLI) Configure firebase
[19-12-11 18:15:43.785] Prepare step completed.
[19-12-11 18:15:45.278] Upload step started.
[19-12-11 18:16:03.211] Upload step completed.
[19-12-11 18:16:11.009] Build step started.
[19-12-11 18:16:24.938] (CLI) ios Build Tooling revision 2019.08.21.1r
[19-12-11 18:16:24.938] (CLI) Build Tooling Hostname administrators-mac-16.local
[19-12-11 18:16:24.938] (CLI) App package not specified. Skipping unzip step.
[19-12-11 18:16:24.938] (CLI) NativeScript CLI version 6.2.2
[19-12-11 18:16:24.938] (CLI) Add platform ios with runtime version 6.2.0
[19-12-11 18:16:29.561] (CLI) Copying template files...
[19-12-11 18:16:32.525] (CLI) Platform ios successfully added. v6.2.0
[19-12-11 18:16:32.525] (CLI) Prepare Project for Platform -  ios
[19-12-11 18:17:13.364] (CLI) Preparing project...
[19-12-11 18:17:13.364] (CLI) Stripping the snapshot flag. Bear in mind that snapshot is only available in Android release builds.
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Hash: 01fecff5a9726d05be53
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Version: webpack 4.27.1
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Time: 68093ms
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Built at: 12/11/2019 4:50:06 AM
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                             Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                              4.js   18.7 KiB       4  [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                              5.js   12.7 KiB       5  [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                              6.js   13.2 KiB       6  [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                              7.js   33.6 KiB       7  [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                  assets/images/MembershipTier.png    203 KiB          [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                  assets/images/icons/overview.png  648 bytes          [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                   assets/images/icons/profile.png  800 bytes          [emitted]

   --------------------------------------

[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                      package.json  112 bytes          [emitted]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                        runtime.js   1.54 KiB       1  [emitted]  runtime
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules.js  241 bytes       3  [emitted]  tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)                                         vendor.js   1.68 MiB       0  [emitted]  vendor
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Entrypoint tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules = runtime.js vendor.js tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules.js
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)   [4] ../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js + 9 modules 238 KiB {0} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       |    10 modules
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [13] ./app/core/services/ui.service.ts 1.37 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [16] ./app/auth/services/auth.service.ts + 2 modules 10.3 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/auth/services/auth.service.ts 8.71 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/auth/models/dizz-loyalty-user.ts 1.29 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/auth/models/login-error.ts 186 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [26] ../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/index.js + 35 modules 66.2 KiB {0} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       |    36 modules
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [47] ./app/shared/storage-key.ts 713 bytes {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [61] ./app/core/services/push-notification.service.ts 2 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [63] ./app/shared/generic-validator.ts 3.09 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [65] ./app/core/services/core.service.ts 708 bytes {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [72] ./app/tutorial/services/tutorial.service.ts 1.63 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)  [95] ./app/auth/services/auth.guard.ts 1.31 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) [117] ./app/auth/services/open-id-discovery.service.ts 1.75 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) [155] ./app/core/services/barcode-resolver.service.ts 393 bytes {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) [157] ./app/shared/shared.module.ts 157 bytes {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) [210] ./app.css 2.63 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) [431] ./main.ts + 32 modules 116 KiB {2} [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./main.ts 1.66 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/app.module.ngfactory.js 13 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/app.module.ts 268 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/app.component.ts 838 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/activity-indicator.service.ts 465 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/app.component.ngfactory.js 3.12 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/http-cache-interceptor.service.ts 2.49 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/http-activity-monitor-interceptor.service.ts 1.32 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/add-base-url-interceptor.service.ts 1.04 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/add-token-interceptor.service.ts 1.33 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/home-page-resolver.service.ts 393 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/services/global-error-handler.service.ts 1.34 KiB [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/core-routing.module.ts 561 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/core/core.module.ts 132 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       | ./app/app-routing.module.ts 703 bytes [built]
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)       |     + 18 hidden modules
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI)     + 514 hidden modules
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) Webpack compilation complete.
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: /private/tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
[19-12-11 18:18:24.689] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
[19-12-11 18:18:26.163] (CLI) Installing pods...
[19-12-11 18:18:27.795] (CLI) Analyzing dependencies
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Downloading dependencies

   --------------------------------------

[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Installing Protobuf (3.11.1)
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Installing ZXingObjC (3.4.3)
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Installing nanopb (0.3.9011)
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Generating Pods project
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Integrating client project
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `DizzLoyaltyApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Pod installation complete! There are 9 dependencies from the Podfile and 22 total pods installed.
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Project successfully prepared (ios)
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Configure firebase
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI) Build for Device
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)    \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/975d4475-ddb0-423c-b181-63934d770963-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)     \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/d76f7842-4a83-4c50-8a87-c0faab0b7be6-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)     \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/7b6c2e3f-b9f3-4594-8df5-821d6f4200e2-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)     \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/2d1de30b-8d26-40b2-bfce-451f6510e4da-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)     \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/29e4439f-006d-4cc9-afe5-3cb223920e77-db\"
  
-----------------------------------------------------

2a24ed0f1bf8-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)     \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/46d21c42-9224-486b-b69a-80b3455ee079-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:39.736] (CLI)     \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI) 1 identity imported.
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI) keychain: \"/Users/builder/Library/Keychains/155fad90-a6f1-4148-b5fe-e1406b7d0b41-db\"
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI) version: 512
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI) class: 0x00000010
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI) attributes:
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000000 <uint32>=0x00000010
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000001 <blob>=0x344434453644343900  \"4D4E6D49\\000\"
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000002 <blob>=<NULL>
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000003 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000004 <uint32>=0x00000000
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000005 <uint32>=0x00000000
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000006 <blob>=0x514ACACE909F92783A14C4FBDD8661E45E2906BF  \"QJ\\312\\316\\220\\237\\222x:\\024\\304\\373\\335\\206a\\344^)\\006\\277\"
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000007 <blob>=<NULL>
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000008 <blob>=0x7B38373139316361322D306663392D313164342D383439612D3030303530326235323132327D00  \"{87191ca2-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}\\000\"
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000009 <uint32>=0x0000002A  \"\\000\\000\\000*\"
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000000A <uint32>=0x00000800
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000000B <uint32>=0x00000800
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000000C <blob>=0x0000000000000000
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000000D <blob>=0x0000000000000000
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000000E <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000000F <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000010 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000011 <uint32>=0x00000000
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000012 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000013 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000014 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000015 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000016 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000017 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000018 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x00000019 <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI)     0x0000001A <uint32>=0x00000001
[19-12-11 18:18:41.463] (CLI) Building project ...
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Processing nanopb-Info.plist
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying pb_encode.h
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying pb_decode.h
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying pb_common.h
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying pb.h
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying nanopb-umbrella.h
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Processing ZXingObjC-Info.plist
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying ZXMultiFinderPatternFinder.h
[19-12-11 18:18:50.605] (CLI) ▸ Copying ZXMultiDetector.h
   
.............................
   
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling FBSDKAccessTokenExpirer.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling FBSDKAccessTokenCache.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling FBSDKAccessToken.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Copying /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/MDFInternationalization/Sources/UIView+MaterialRTL.h
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Copying /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/MDFInternationalization/Sources/UIImage+MaterialRTL.h
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Copying /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/MDFInternationalization/Sources/NSString+MaterialBidi.h
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Copying /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/MDFInternationalization/Sources/NSLocale+MaterialRTL.h
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Copying /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/MDFInternationalization/Sources/MDFRTL.h
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Copying /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/MDFInternationalization/Sources/MDFInternationalization.h
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDURLSessionProvider.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDURLQueryComponent.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDTokenUtilities.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDTokenResponse.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDTokenRequest.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDServiceDiscovery.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDServiceConfiguration.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDScopes.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDScopeUtilities.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDResponseTypes.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDRegistrationResponse.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDRegistrationRequest.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDIDToken.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDGrantTypes.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDFieldMapping.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ▸ Compiling OIDErrorUtilities.m
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) The following build commands failed:
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) \tCompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) \tCompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) \tCompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[19-12-11 18:20:00.604] (CLI) (3 failures)
[19-12-11 18:20:03.983] (CLI) ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[19-12-11 18:20:03.983] (CLI) The following build commands failed:
[19-12-11 18:20:03.983] (CLI) \tCompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[19-12-11 18:20:03.983] (CLI) \tCompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[19-12-11 18:20:03.983] (CLI) \tCompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[19-12-11 18:20:03.983] (CLI) (3 failures)
[19-12-11 18:20:32.602] Build step completed.
[19-12-11 18:20:32.608] Build failed. Build failed. Reason is: 'Build failed with error code 2'. Additional information: [00:03:34.639] [WARN]  ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
[00:03:34.640] [WARN]   CompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
[00:03:36.996] [ERROR] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/DerivedData/DizzLoyaltyApp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DizzLoyaltyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.o /tmp/builds/_/a4f3c2f437d19d5ec531222211ed6a887e3ea5ae/6.2.2/6.2.0/DizzLoyaltyApp/platforms/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
'Build failed with error code 2'.
```

**I have tried**

1. Rebuilding the project after deleting platforms, node_modules, and hooks folder.
2. I already went through [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553872/nativescript-build-failed-with-error-code-2), [Link 2](https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/357), and [Link 3](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4911)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!